# Select Month w/ Most Days in Multi Month Range in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff, dateadd

Sorry if this has been asked, but I didn't find anything when searching: I have a large table of ~100k rows in SQL Server. Within each row is a date range, which in many cases spreads across multiple months (and years to a lesser extent). The ranges are typically about 30-35 days however they usually don't start at the the 1st of the month. An example of a typical date range is 01/10/2017-02/11/2017.

I'm looking for the most efficient way to output the month with the most days within in that range as it's own column. I'm doing the same thing for the year

Right now I have the following in my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   a.START_DATE, 
   a.END_DATE,
   cast(month(dateadd(day, datediff(day, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date)/2, a.Start_Date)) as tinyint) as Main_Month,
   cast(year(dateadd(day, datediff(day, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date)/2, a.Start_Date)) as smallint) as Main_Year
FROM TABLE
```

The output from that query using the above date range example would give me:

```
Start_Date: 01/10/2017 End_Date: 02/11/2017 Main_Month: 1 Main Year: 2017
```

That method has worked alright, but it slows when being done for all rows in the table. Are there any more efficient alternatives that I can use for the Main_Month and Main_Year columns?

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:

- By "month w/ the most days within a date range", using my example range of 01/10/2017-02/11/2017, since that range contains 21 days in January and only 11 in February, the output I'd get for Main_Month is 1. Also since the year is 2017 throughout the range the output I'd get for Main_Year is 2017
- For ties, I'd go with the 1st month containing the max # of days. In the example of, 6/20/2017 - 9/5/2017 I'd go with 7, since that is the 1st month with 31 days in the range

Comment: "I'm looking for the most efficient way to output the month with the most days within in that range as it's own column."  I just don't get this.  Can you provide both sample data and desired results?

Comment: How is a tie handled in your business logic? For example, if a date range is 6/20/2017 - 9/5/2017, both July and August 2017 have 31 days in this range. Which one would be identified?

Comment: In addition to your concern about efficiency, you should know that your current code does not solve the problem as is. It merely returns the month and year of the mid-point of the range, which might not be the longest month at all. For example, for 1/10/2017 - 4/2/2017, your code will give Feb 2017, whereas Mar 2017 actually has more days.

Comment: @GregViers That's correct. It's the best I was able to come up with though.

Comment: Does the solution need to be perfectly correct, or can it allow for errors of 1-2 days?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be perfect. There's some room for error

Comment: That helps - in that case your approach is actually a good one because of the simplicity of the calculation and we can choose to ignore the different lengths of months. It means this is just an efficiency question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discused in the comments above, this solution is not perfectly accurate, but it mirrors the accuracy of the original slower solution:

```
SELECT b.START_DATE, b.END_DATE, month(b.mid_point) as Main_Month, year(b.midpoint) as Main_Year FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
       a.START_DATE, 
       a.END_DATE,
       dateadd(day, datediff(day, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date)/2, a.Start_Date) as mid_Point
    FROM a) as b
```

You should be able to speed it up by making these two changes. First, only compute the datediff and dateadd once, then take it from the derived table to get the two fields you need. Next, don't bother with casting, since Month() and year() both do that for you. Were you able to see a speed difference with this method?

Comment: It did help a bit w/ the performance. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: If you create a view in your sql server that calculates the midpoint, you can create an index on it for the midpoint column and see more gains.

Answer (score 0):

I think using CASE statements could be more efficient, and if you can avoid casting, like this:

```
,  CASE WHEN datediff(day, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date) + 1 - DAY(a.END_Date) < DAY(a.END_DATE) THEN MONTH(a.End_Date) 
    ELSE MONTH(a.Start_Date) END AS Main_Month
 , CASE WHEN YEAR(a.END_Date) = YEAR(a.Start_Date) THEN YEAR(a.Start_Date)
        WHEN datediff(day, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date) + 1 - DAY(a.END_Date) < DAY(a.END_DATE) THEN  YEAR(a.End_Date) 
    ELSE YEAR(a.Start_Date) END AS Main_Year
```

Comment: Hmm... I have just seen that the date range may cover more than one whole month, so maybe this is not good logic. Even so, the possibility of using CASE to narrow down the calculation steps may still apply?